# How do I calculate the position on a circle based on a progress value?

Tags: algorithm, math, trigonometry

Currently I'm working on a orbit system for a game. I've got it so an object will move along a circle based on a progress value that'll be between 0.0 and 1.0 (0.5 being half way around the circle). I calculate this like this:

```
float angle = Mathf.Deg2Rad * 360 * t;
float xPos = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xAxis;
float yPos = Mathf.Cos(angle) * yAxis;

return new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0.0f);
```

With t simply being deltatime and the xAxis/yAxis variables being the radius of the circle.
What I'm a little stuck on currently though is how I could possibly get the progress around the circle based on a poisition. So if I have an object that hits the bottom of the circle, how do I calculate that to be a progress of 0.5?

Comment: If xAxis != yAxis you actually have an ellipse rather than a circle. If you want your orbits to be physically accurate you should look at [Kepler's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step: Find out the angle of your given position with the y-axis.

Second step: Calculate the fraction of a full circle (360 degs) that your angle has.

First step involves a bit of trigonometry, and there you have to make sure to get the right type of angle based on what quadrant you're in. Second step should be trivial then.

You can check out the `atan2` function that's available in many programming languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

It gives the angle between a point (x, y) and the positive x-axis. So then in your case, depending on where your circle starts, you'd then shift that by 90 degrees to get the angle with the positive y-axis. Other than that it should work fine though.